# MAMP and PHP new versions

Tags: mamp, php-8.2

Do you know if MAMP (free) can support versions of PHP newer than 8.2.0, like 8.2.8? I have installed the 8.2.8 version, it appears in the switcher options of the dialog box of MAMP (together with the 8.2.0, the other available version), I use it, but the `phpinfo();` is still showing me the PHP 8.2.0 version.

I have installed the folder `php-8.2.8` renamed to `php8.2.8` to be compatible with file naming of MAMP. The location of PHP is `usr/local/Cellar/php8.2.8`. And also is copied in the `MAMP/bin/php/` directory.

The `php.ini` just shows you the version I am using, right? I can not set up versions in thi files, I guess.

I placed the folder of PHP8.2.8 (renamed accordingly) in the MAMP/bin/ folder, the other versions of php are renamed with “...xxxxx” at the end, so I have just active two versions, 8.2.8 and 8.2.0. The apache `httpd.conf` confirms that is loading the PHP8.2.8 version.

As last thing, I created a folder called `php8.2.8` inside the `MAMP/conf/` directory, and I pasted the “php.ini” file in it. So, What am I doing wrong?